# Error "no data foun" on insert in my trigger ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've three tables:

```
create table person(
 id_per number(1) primary key not null,
 name_per varchar(15) not null);

create table training(
 id_training number(1) primary key not null,
 start_training date not null, 
 final_training date not null);

create table training_person(
 id_tp number(3) primary key not null, 
 id_per number(8) not null, 
 id_training number(1) not null);
```

I created a trigger whose function is verify that the user can't to insert in the table training_person if the user have a active training ... but when I want to insert a new register but the person don't have any training registered before, oracle show me the following error: "no data found".

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VERIFY_TRAINING
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON training_person
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
GET_FINAL_TRAINING DATE;  
GET_START_TRAINING DATE;
BEGIN      
select MAX(final_training) into GET_FINAL_TRAINING 
from training t join training_person x on t.id_training=x.id_training join person e on e.id_per=x.id_per
WHERE e.id_per=:new.id_per;

select start_training into GET_START_TRAINING 
from training t join training_person x on t.id_training=x.id_training
where t.id_training=:new.id_training;

IF (GET_FINAL_TRAINING > GET_START_TRAINING) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20091,'U CANT INSERT TRAINING.');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO training_person values(:new.id_tp,:new.id_per,:new.id_training);
END;
```

I'm learning Oracle, so I dunno which is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you are learning oracle, then do the right thing from the start, that is - forget triggers. Create a procedure, and store all the logic there. Oracle itself suggest and recommends NOT to implement business logic with triggers.

Comment: You seem to have already handled `no_data_found` in your code, then tell us what's your question?

Comment: @Ychdziu thx for the recommendation

Comment: @KaushikNayak yes the exception is here in my code line but doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work. Please tell us what's the error thrown.